# Cardinality and Bijection problem.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

[image]

I think both (a) and (b) are true, because all the sets in the questions are infinite uncountable, so we can construct a bijection map. For question a, [0,1] and [0,1] are exactly the same set so I am not sure how the map [0,1] to [0,1] union A.
If I construct a function K defined as follow, K(x) = {f(x)=(x-1)/2 if x belongs to A, g(x)=x/2 for all x belongs to the image of f(x), and h(x) if otherwise. Is it a bijection map?
For question (b), I am not sure how to show there exists a bijection map.

Comment: Is there any technique you know to show that two sets have the same cardinality?

Comment: I have learn to show two sets to be equivalent, we have to construct a bijective map between that 2 sets..

Comment: Hmm.... I don't know what you do or don't know. Do you know what saying $|M|\le |N|$ means?  Do you know that $M \subset N \implies |M| \le |N|$?  Can you figure out how that would be equivalent to $|M| \le |M\cup K|$ for all $K$?  These problems both are direct applications of that.

Comment: "I have learn to show two sets to be equivalent, we have to construct a bijective map between that 2 sets"  Nitpick.  You don't have to construct the map. You just have to prove that such a bijective map exists.  There are ways to prove that without actually making the map.

Comment: @HTLL: Do you know that if $A$ and $B$ have the same cardinality, and $A\subseteq X\subseteq B$, then $X$ has the same cardinality as $A$ and $B$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, Oh, so are you suggesting when then equality hold, then X has the same cardinality as A and B? Base on that, we only need to consider how to show A and B have the cardinality ?

Comment: @HTLL: Yes: $A\subseteq X$ tells you that $|A|\le|X|$, and $X\subseteq B$ tells you that $|X|\le|B|$, so if $|A|=|B|$ we have $|A|\le|X|\le|B|=|A|$, and therefore $|A|=|X|=|B|$. Whether you can use this result depends on just what knowledge of cardinalities you have available; the proof that in this case there is a bijection between $A$ and $X$, for instance, is fairly complicated.

Comment: @HTLL: I do have one other comment. The fact that two sets are both uncountable is not enough to ensure that there is a bijection between them. For example, $\Bbb R$ and $\wp(\Bbb R)$ are both uncountable, but there is no surjection from $\Bbb R$ to $\wp(\Bbb R)$, let alone a bijection. However, in this case we have more information than that.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathfrak{c} = |[0,1]| \le|[0,1\ \cup A| \le \mathfrak{c} + |A| \le \mathfrak{c} + \mathfrak{c}=\mathfrak{c}$ so yes for a).

$\mathfrak{c}=|[x_0-\frac{r}{2}, x_0 + \frac{r}{2}]| \le |B| \le |[0,1] = \mathfrak{c}$ so yes for b) too.